# Making an exact copy of a Windows installation

Tags: windows, backup, fsarchiver

My goal is pretty simple: I need to make an exact copy of a Windows partition. Then I can wipe it down, play with it, and when I'm done, I can re-copy the partition back and have everything back in order.

I achieved this in the past by saving the partition table + using http://www.fsarchiver.org but the whole setup is a bit "iffy". The end result is not "exactly" the same as the original and after 2-3 months I had to format the disk.

Does anyone have a better solution? Maybe a dd copy?

Comment: This may be answered here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140957/how-can-i-back-up-win7-before-installing-mint-alongside-it/140966#140966

Comment: `dd` is great to backup the disk's first sector, containing the MBR and partition table. It can also be used to make an image of the partition, but `ntfsclone` is probably a better choice (as I elaborated below).

Answer (score 2):

I think that [ntfsclone](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ntfsclone) might be really helpfull here. As mentioned in the manuall: "...ntfsclone can be useful to make backups, an exact snapshot of an NTFS filesystem and restore it later on..."
ntfsclone is part of the ntfs-3g package.

Comment: I also use and recommend `ntfsclone`. Because it understands the NTFS filesystem it only reads the stuff it needs to reconstruct the filesytem on a partition, so unless the partition is full the files it makes will generally be smaller than an exact clone of the partition's bytes made using `dd` and copying with `ntfsclone` will be faster than using `dd`, especially if the partition has a lot of empty space.

Comment: FWIW, a few months ago I successfully used ntfsclone to clone fresh Windows 7 installations to around a dozen identical machines; it was **significantly** faster than installing each one individually from CD. (Yes, these were all legal installations, done for a community organization with the appropriate licenses).